# I could get a data from only certain point of rect not an entire rectangular

Tags: javascript, html, image, events, canvas

I'm trying to implement eventListener for HTML Canvas.
I would like to add event to rect from SVG canvas

Problem is that
I could get a data from only certain point of rect not an entire rectangular.

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", e => {
          this.mousePos = {
            x: e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
            y: e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop
          };
          console.log(this.mousePos.x, this.mousePos.y);

          const pixel = hitCtx.getImageData(
            this.mousePos.x,
            this.mousePos.y,
            1,
            1
          ).data;
          console.log(pixel);

          var r = pixel[0];
          var g = pixel[1];
          var b = pixel[2];
          const color = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";

          console.log(color);
  
          if (color == "rgb(255,59,59)") {
            console.log("click on the pipe");
          }
});
```

https://codepen.io/chikichaka/pen/yLaMbwe

[image]

[image]

I read this article and followed second way which is using color.

https://lavrton.com/hit-region-detection-for-html5-canvas-and-how-to-listen-to-click-events-on-canvas-shapes-815034d7e9f8/

Comment: You seem to drawing the pipe, the red line, on the element called canvas but testing the clicked pixel against the canvas called hitCanvas, on which there appears to be nothing, apart from one pixel possibly. What is supposed to be drawn on hitCanvas. Also, this does not as it stands seem to have anything to do with SVG. Is something missing in your codepen?

Comment: @A Haworth sorry. I mistyped it is just for HTML Canvas. I will edit. also I read this article about adding an event of canvas by color. I will add this article to my post. and I edit my codepen. Thanks for feedback!

Comment: Is the idea that you draw something else on hitCanvas but test whether it’s on the pipe by having an overlay of a diagrammatic pipe on canvas?

Comment: @A Haworth Right. I would like to add event to just red pipe not entire canvas overlay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial aim is to check whether the user has clicked on the red rectangle in the canvas.

The code given tries to do this by looking at the pixel in the click position and deciding whether it is the color (a sort of red) or not. If not then there has been no click on the 'pipe'.

However, in the codepen given this test is done at the right position, but not on the canvas which has the red pipe drawn on it. It is done on hitCanvas instead. If we change to test against the canvas on which the red pipe is drawn we get the correct clicks.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const hitCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const hitCtx = hitCanvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 200;


hitCanvas.width = 300;
hitCanvas.height = 200;

var width = 300;
var height = 10;
var startX = 0;
var startY = 100;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.translate(200, 30);
ctx.rotate((31.5 * Math.PI) / -180);
ctx.translate(-225, -65);
ctx.rect(this.startX, this.startY, this.width, this.height);
ctx.fillStyle = "#ff3b3b";
ctx.fill();

hitCtx.beginPath();
hitCtx.translate(200, 30);
hitCtx.rotate((-1 * Math.PI) / -180);
hitCtx.translate(-225, -40);
hitCtx.rect(this.startX, this.startY, this.width, this.height);
hitCtx.fillStyle = "#ff3b3b";
hitCtx.fill();

canvas.addEventListener("click", e => {
          this.mousePos = {
            x: e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
            y: e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop
          };
          console.log(this.mousePos.x, this.mousePos.y);

          const pixel = ctx.getImageData(//CHANGED TO ctx TO ENSURE WE TEST ARE ON THE RED RECTANGLE */
            this.mousePos.x,
            this.mousePos.y,
            1,
            1
          ).data;
          console.log(pixel);

          var r = pixel[0];
          var g = pixel[1];
          var b = pixel[2];
          const color = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";

          console.log(color);
  
          if (color == "rgb(255,59,59)") {
            console.log("click on the pipe");
          }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" />
```

This solves the problem as posed in the question. However, there are then further questions - is in fact a 'proper' drawing of something supposed to be in hitCanvas which is the one seen by the user, with the other canvas being laid on top so that a 'real' pipe is shown as hit? This may need to be the subject of an additional question if it is not now clear as to what is happening.

Comment: @A Haworth I'm not sure about it. Checking the rectangle, it is working well without another canvas. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
let y = e.clientY - rect.top;
console.log(rect);
```